# How to do INSERT in Pyramid using khufu_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to learn python and I've picked Pyramid framework. However, I didn't want to use the ORM provided by the sqlalchemy but rather write pure sql (I am still using sqlalchemy though). I am as well using khufu_sqlalchemy to set it up.

However, I am unable to do inserts into database. Transaction is being started but it is never commited..
My code:

```
    db = dbsession(request)
    db.execute('insert into users (email, password) values (:email, :password)' , {'email':email, 'password':password})
```

Is there a way to autocommit? The documentation is really sparse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

khufu follows the pyramid practice of using a transaction manager to handle your database connections. This means that there is code (`ZopeTransactionExtension` in your sessionmaker initialization) that hooks the database session and tracks changes. When changes are detected they will be automatically committed at the end of the request if no errors occur. If you are bypassing the ORM and calling execute yourself, you can either 1) turn off the transaction manager and call commit yourself or 2) mark the session as dirty after doing `execute` so that the connection will think stuff changed and call commit automatically for you. The second way is preferred because if you call commit prematurely yourself the rest of the code may fail and yet data is still persisted in your database. To do the second way, use the `mark_changed` function from the extension.

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import mark_changed
session = DBSession()
mark_changed(session)
```

As a side note, if you do want to force the transaction to commit before the end of a request, you can do that via

```
import transaction
transaction.commit()
```

But again, this will happen automatically at the end of a request if no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html

```
db.commit()
```

is what you are looking for. Check further documentation for autocommit.

Comment: This will not work if using the transaction extension. It will result in an exception because the transaction manager is handling commits for you.